# HashMap containsKey() method isn't working for certain elements

Tags: java, hashmap

The constructor takes in two arrays, and I want to put them in my HashMap but if the map already contains a word from one of the arrays, then I want to throw an exception. This works UNLESS the duplicate term is the last one in the array terms. Why is this happening?

```
private HashMap<String, Double> wordToWgt = new HashMap<String, Double>();
private TST t = new TST();
double maxWeight = 0.0;
private String maxWord = "";
public Autocomplete(String[] terms, double[] weights) {
    if (terms.length != weights.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
            if (weights[i] < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            else if (wordToWgt.containsKey(terms[i])) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            else if (weights[i] > maxWeight) {
                maxWeight = weights[i];
                maxWord = terms[i];
            }
            t.insert(terms[i], weights[i]);
            wordToWgt.put(terms[i], weights[i]);
        }
    }
```

//        System.out.println(wordToWgt.keySet());
    }

Comment: Please include the `terms` and `weights` that cause the program to fail

Comment: Have you tried `new Autocomplete (new String[]{"a","a"}, new double[] {1, 1});`?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  Can you tell us what values you're passing to this method, that are causing the unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see anything wrong with your code, so I'm going to suggest some alternative explanations.

You are (I guess) using the output of

```
 System.out.println(wordToWgt.keySet());
```

to tell you that there is a duplicate.  However, the key set returned by `keySet` is a genuine set (in the context of the semantics of `String.equals`).  Therefore there *cannot* be duplicates.

So what you are seeing as duplicates are ... in fact ... not duplicates at all.  How is that possible?

- There could be a leading or trailing whitespace character on one of the strings.  That can be easy to miss.
- It could be a [homoglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) problem.

It could also be that your / your tool chain is not rebuilding the code properly; i.e. the code you are running may not match the source code you are looking at / editing.

---

P.S.  The fact that you are seeing this on the last element only could be just a coincidence, or it could be an artefact of the way that the input strings are being produced.

Comment: Great advice here. Maybe print out the result of `equals()`, `hashCode()` and even the bytes of the pairs of strings that you expect to collide but aren't.